# Getting table from website using requests

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to get the information from the table in this website "https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/fb/financials" -> "Details View".

I tried to monitor the network in developer tools.
[image]

Then, I tried to open the following link from python:

```
content = requests.get("https://api-global.morningstar.com/sal-service/v1/stock/newfinancials/0P0000A66L/incomeStatement/detail").content
```

but I get "You have not provided any credentials,  please contact the API owner for the API you are trying to use."

How do I provided headers or credentials so that I can get the info from python?

Comment: Have you tried adding all the parameters after "detail?" at the end in your request?

Comment: @thenullptr Yes, same effect.